# Preserving Row Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $B$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, then the rank of $AB$ is the same as the rank of $A$ for every $m\times n$ matrix $A$.

This is what I have thus far:

If the matrix $B$ is invertible, then $B$ is nonsingular. If $B$ is nonsingular, then the columns of $B$ are linearly independent, because the rank of $B$ is $n$. If the columns of $B$ are linearly independent, then the product $AB$ preserves the row space of $A$, because every row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ and the columns of $B$. Because the rank of $B$ is $n$, no row of $A$ can be removed from $AB$, since there are no zero columns in $B$.

However, the last sentence only addresses zero rows. For instance, two rows of $B$ could be identical, and cancel out in $AB$, but my solution does not address that. How do I tie in the linear independence of $B$ into the answer?

Comment: Have you established yet that, in general, $\text{rank}(AB) \leq$ rank$A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the general inequality rank$(MN) \leq$ rank$(M)$, we can say that
$$
\text{rank}(A) \geq \text{rank}(AB) \geq \text{rank}([AB]B^{-1}) = \text{rank}(A)
$$
which proves your statement.

In order to prove that rank$(MN) \leq$ rank$(M)$, note that the columns of $MN$ are linear combinations of the columns of $M$.  So, as a result, the span of the columns of $MN$ is a subset of the span of the columns of $M$.

---

Alternatively: suppose $y = Mx$ is in the column space of $M$.  Then $y = MB(B^{-1}x)$ is also in the column space of $MB$.